# Managing "What's New in This Version" field for different locales in Apple App Store Connect

Tags: app-store-connect-api

Do you automatically populate the "What's New in This Version" field in Apple App Store Connect for different locales? The API seems outdated, and I'm struggling to find alternative options. Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated!

I attempted to utilize the existing API for the "What's New in This Version" field in Apple App Store Connect, expecting it to support various locales. Unfortunately, the API proved outdated, and I couldn't find alternative solutions. As a result, I'm seeking advice on how to handle this issue effectively.

Comment: Welcome!  To help focus in on precisely which API documentation you've looked at, could you edit your question and provide a link to it?  Thanks.